# Make a list of all indexes of the same element from a grouped list of tuples

Tags: python, blender

I'm making a script that turns pixel art into voxel art. I have an image and have created a grouped list of each pixel's RGBA values as tuples

```
RGBA_list = list(img.pixels)
    
gl = [RGBA_list[ipx] for ipx in range(0, len(RGBA_list), 4)]
```

This is for pixel art so many of the colours are the exact same and there are a small number of unique ones. Is there a way to get multiple lists of the indices of each colour?

Or better worded: get each individual colour within the image, then for each colour get a list of indices from the grouped list with that colour

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to you question as it makes it way easier to answer it. For example you could make an example `RGBA_list` and show us what output you would expect. Then everyone would be able to answer using the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list with repeated values and you want to convert that into value->list_of_index_where_it_occurs map. You can make use of [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects). (other way is to use setdefault, but defaultdict make it easier and cleaner.)
Please see example below:

```
>>> info_list = [random.randint(1,5) for x in range(100)]
>>> info_list
[4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 2, 2]

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> info_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, x in enumerate(info_list):
...     info_dict[x].append(i)
... 
>>> info_dict.keys()
dict_keys([4, 5, 2, 3, 1])
>>> info_dict[1]
[7, 13, 16, 20, 21, 25, 28, 34, 36, 38, 54, 59, 62, 63, 73, 77, 90, 95]
```